# How do I check for CSS styling with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

Why am I unable to test for CSS styling like this:

```
if (document.getElementById("myText").style.outline == "10px solid black")
{
  // Do something
}
```

or

```
if (document.getElementById("myText").style.match("outline: 10px solid 
black"))
{
  // Do something;
}
```

when I have:

```
#myText
{
  outline: 10px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(document.getElementById("myText").style.outline);` to see what the output is before comparing it in your if statement? I think you will find it returns nothing / blank

Comment: @NewToJS It returns: "black solid 10px", and on the next line "undefined"

Comment: Ah so you're using inline css rather than applying the styles via `.css` or in the styles tag.

Comment: @NewToJS I am using the style tag.

Comment: No, you are using the style attribute. A style tag would be `<style> //CSS HERE </style>` and the style attribute would be `style="CSS HERE"` which is inline styles and to your question it makes a world of difference.

Comment: @NewToJS Sorry, my bad. I didn't realize that I had added the style both through tag and attribute while testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property will only return styles that are set on the element's `style` attribute or in javascript, so you won't see styles that applied separately by CSS.

Furthermore, there are multiple ways of expressing the same set of CSS properties, and the browser is generating a string that describes the current properties (rather than returning whatever string you used to set them). Therefore the browser can and will reorder the property values and/or convert them to other units (e.g. `black` -> `rgb(0,0,0)`) so testing for a particular string is never going to be reliable. E.g.

```js
document.body.style.outline = "10px solid black"
console.log(document.body.style.outline)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume [**getComputedStyle**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) will help in finding the applied style

```js
var elem1 = document.getElementById("myText"),
  style = window.getComputedStyle(elem1, null);
console.log(style.outline)
```

```css
#myText {
  outline: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="myText">Text</div>
```

Comment: but note that even then the returned string doesn't necessarily match the original CSS and could vary from browser to browser, so testing for a specific string is a bad idea